# how to set view width from font width

Tags: android, width, spinner, font-size

I have an EditText and a Spinner in a horizontal layout.  I'd like the spinner to be only as large as necessary to hold its widest text and the EditText to take the remaining space.  Is there an easy way to do this?

For example, ideally, I'd like to specify the spinner's width as some multiple of the average font width, declared as an attribute in the xml file.

Otherwise, I suppose I need to do something at runtime such as get the text width of each item in the spinner and take the max + some allowance for the radio-button icon.

This is my xml:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal" >

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/text" />

  <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Right.  That should work.   Don't know why I overlooked that.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work.  It gives only enough width for the radio button.

Comment: from where radio button came?

Comment: There is a difference: I have mine declared as a "dropdown".  If I take that out, the width works.  However, I would prefer a dropdown.

Comment: I added the xml to my post, above.

Comment: use `fill_parent` width for `LinearLayout and `EditText`

Comment: Well, it's working now.  I rebuilt everything - I don't know why it gave me a width of the radio button earlier.  Thanks for your help.  By the way, according to Android docs, fill_parent is replaced by match_parent.

Comment: that is still a confusing part for me:) As per my experince it never works same! What my understanding is that `match_parent` actually match with its parent..